# How do I represent subclass invocations in Activity Diagrams

Tags: java, uml

1. Class 1 creates Class 2 which is a subclass of class 3
2. Class 1 invokes a method on Class 2, which doesn't implement that method and instead hands it off to class 3
3. Class 3 then calls a method on Class 2

If I represent all 3 classes on the diagram, and then draw an arrow between class 1 and 3, it looks like 1 is directly invoking 3, which it isn't. However, I also don't want to make it look like Class 2 is implementing that method.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking about something in an Activity Diagram or how to represent something in a class diagram? BTW it feels wrong that Class 3 would call a method on Class 2, since Class 2 is a subclass of Class 3 and should not be known to Class 3

Comment: Apologies, how to represent the interaction in a class diagram. I think your rephrasing answered it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have a fundamental error in your thought. SDs and ADs do not show classes, but instances. And there are only two instances here, namely that of `Class1` and that of `Class2` being a subclass of `Class3`. So the internal call from `Class2`'s instance goes to itself.

The structure is like this:

[image]

And the SD like that:

[image]

In an AD it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: That makes sense. even though Class 2 is getting behavior from Class 3, Class 3 isn't being instantiated so it wouldn't show. duh! Thanks Thomas!